# How to solve `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error when install gcloud?

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I tried to install gcloud in MacOs but failed. I tried two python versions 3.7.4 and 3.9.1 but both have the same issue. how can I install the `gcloud`? Is there any other dependencies I need?

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.9.1

$ sh install.sh --screen-reader=true
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at <https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics>. This data is
handled in accordance with our privacy policy
<https://cloud.google.com/terms/cloud-privacy-notice>. You may choose to opt in this
collection now (by choosing 'Y' at the below prompt), or at any time in the
future by running the following command:

    gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting false

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (y/N)?  y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 930, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/connection.py", line 361, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 382, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Users/joey/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Users/joey/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/joey/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 232, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 210, in main
    Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 151, in Install
    _CLI.Execute(['--quiet', 'components', 'list'])
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 1008, in Execute
    self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 1045, in _HandleAllErrors
    exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self.__known_error_handler)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/exceptions.py", line 551, in HandleError
    core_exceptions.reraise(exc)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/six/__init__.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 982, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 809, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/components/list.py", line 102, in Run
    result = update_manager.List(show_hidden=args.show_hidden,
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 714, in List
    to_print, current_version, latest_version = self._GetPrintListWithDiff()
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 750, in _GetPrintListWithDiff
    _, diff = self._GetStateAndDiff(command_path='components.list')
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 641, in _GetStateAndDiff
    latest_snapshot = self._GetLatestSnapshot(version=version,
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 624, in _GetLatestSnapshot
    return snapshots.ComponentSnapshot.FromURLs(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/snapshots.py", line 178, in FromURLs
    data = [
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/snapshots.py", line 179, in <listcomp>
    (ComponentSnapshot._DictFromURL(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/snapshots.py", line 204, in _DictFromURL
    response = installers.MakeRequestViaRequests(url, command_path)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 203, in MakeRequestViaRequests
    return _RawRequestViaRequests(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 251, in _RawRequestViaRequests
    return retryer.RetryOnException(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 195, in RetryOnException
    exceptions.reraise(exc_info[1], tb=exc_info[2])
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/six/__init__.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 176, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs), None
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py", line 281, in _ExecuteRequestAndRaiseExceptions
    response = requests_session.get(
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/transport.py", line 243, in WrappedRequest
    response = orig_request(*modified_args, **modified_kwargs)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/requests.py", line 198, in WrappedRequest
    return orig_request_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joey/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Comment: Are you behind an SSL proxy os something similar?

Comment: No I don't think so. I don't have any proxy configured in my network.

Comment: Was your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many possible reasons for this error, proxy configuration would be the one but as you mentioned you have no proxy  configured to your network so, the cause could be something else. In order to Authenticate whether this error has occurred  due to proxy or not, you can try running below commands:

```
$ curl https://dl.google.com/

Output: <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome"> Found  </a>
```

If you get a different output from the above mentioned one then, you're behind a proxy or portal.

You can refer to  this stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220727/sslhandshakeerror-with-httplib2-python2-while-installing-google-cloud-sdk), where a  cloud support user has given an answer by providing various possible reasons that could cause this SSL error, he has also provided the workaround for  resolving this error.
Try disabling antivirus settings, if there is any such software installed.

Comment: yes I got this output: `<a href="https://www.google.com/chrome">Found</a>`. but not sure why it still happens since I don't have any configuration on proxy/cert

Comment: okay, can you refer to the provided thread in the answer, there are various reasons mentioned along with the workaround, check and revert back.

Comment: Try disabling antivirus settings, if there is any such software installed.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Is my answer helpful?

Comment: This did not work, here is the only solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71601678/4833285

Answer (score 15):

Run below command to disable ssl verification

```
gcloud config set auth/disable_ssl_validation  True
```

Comment: THANK YOU!. THIS COMMAND SOLVED MY ISSUE WITH GCLOUD CERTIFICATES.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue when running the install script because by definition `gcloud` hasn't been installed yet.

Comment: in general, it is a bad practice to disable ssl cert verification at first place due to security reasons, but it always depends on the context and the nature of your queries and sometimes can be "acceptable" thing to do.

Comment: This did not work, here is the only solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71601678/4833285

Answer (score 5):

adding export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="/usr/bin/python3" to my .zshrc (zshell profile) solved the problem for me. I am using a mac.

Until i added the above to my profile, this issue didn't go away but i also did the following not sure if all these steps were needed in solving this issue:

1. Install latest python 3 from https://www.python.org/downloads/. I used python 3.10.4.
2. Ran python 3.10 Install Certificates.command by going to Applications folder, then python 3.10 and running "Install Certificates.command".
3. added my corporate cert in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Extract the google-cloud-sdk.zip that the installer downloads.
2. Open up google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\session.py
3. Change the line "self.verify = True" to "self.verify = False"
4. Run the install.bat in the root if the directory you extracted to.
5. Profit

Comment: This solution worked, except I couldn't find the zip - gcloud downloads as a installer.exe.

For anyone looking, I've found the zip here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive#windows-zip

In the first step, there is a link to download .zip file.

Comment: This did not work, here is the only solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71601678/4833285

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anyone facing this issue on Windows, I was unable to find the `google-cloud-sdk.zip` file that Matt D mentioned, however after the installation failed I found the extracted files at the following location:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk`

Using this folder location, I followed the steps outlined by Matt D and was able to complete the installation.